# Xcode NSData to Json returns null

Tags: ios, json, xcode

```
NSData *urlDatat = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

NSDictionary* json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlDatat options:0 error:&error];
NSString *urlDataString =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlDatat encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlDatat options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
```

Both `json1` and `json` return null. Actual JSON data from the server is `={"statusCode":"1","message":"success","utcMilliSeconds":"1501953923847"}`

Comment: Is there any output in the `error` parameter?

Comment: Use the `error` parameter. Also, is `urlDatat` nil?

Comment: How do you know "Actual JSON data from the server"? Did you print it? Did you print urlDataString? Or did you type the URL into a browser and assume that would be what you get?

Comment: Quite likely that you are using http, which isn't going to work. Use https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

`NSDictionary *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlDatat options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];`

**UPDATED**

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.kidstriangle.com/KTStandaloneAPI/Common/GetUtcMilliSeconds"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Comment: I had tried still no luck. here is my server url : http://api.kidstriangle.com/KTStandaloneAPI/Common/GetUtcMilliSeconds

Comment: NSString *responseString its debugging variable you can remove it

Comment: Why NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves? Doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: yes you right, you can change it to NSJSONReadingMutableContainers, but it's working solution!

Comment: did you check it?

Comment: Thanks this had worked for me, as i am newbee my count is considered but not incremented on the public vote.